# MYSQL select arithmetic with column results

Tags: mysql, select

I have gotten to this result from my table for two underliers TQQQ and SQQQ

```
select TradeDate, Stock_Short, LastPrice*Volume as USDVolume from aktien 
where Stock_Short ="TQQQ" OR Stock_Short = "SQQQ" order by TradeDate desc
```

which gives this result

[image: Result]

looks like this

```
2018-10-30  SQQQ     1131165621.6
2018-10-30  TQQQ     1100960774.12
2018-10-29  SQQQ     996285358.9
2018-10-29  TQQQ     1263999527.63
2018-10-26  SQQQ     831584079.95
2018-10-26  TQQQ     1496815364.75
2018-10-25  SQQQ     608926709.68
```

Now i want to subtract TQQQ-SQQQ for each calendar day in the table.

```
2018-10-30 -30,204,847
2018-10-29 etc ...
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT a.Stock_Short,a.TradeDate,b.Stock_Short,a.lastprice,a.volume,b.lastprice,b.volume,(a.volume * a.lastprice) - (b.volume * b.lastprice) from aktien a join aktien b on a.TradeDate = b.TradeDate where a.Stock_Short = 'TQQQ' and b.Stock_Short = 'SQQQ' ;

Answer (score 3):

- You can do a `Group By` on `TradeDate`, and you can use either [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) or [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) to conditionally evaluate the [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) as per the `Stock_Short` values.
- Eventually, you can simply calculate the difference using the conditionally summed up values.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  TradeDate, 
  (
   SUM(IF(Stock_Short = "TQQQ", LastPrice * Volume, 0)) - 
   SUM(IF(Stock_Short = "SQQQ", LastPrice * Volume, 0)) 
  ) AS difference 
FROM aktien 
WHERE Stock_Short IN ("TQQQ","SQQQ")
GROUP BY TradeDate 
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC
```

---

Using `Case .. When`, the query would look as follows:

```
SELECT 
  TradeDate, 
  (
   SUM(CASE WHEN Stock_Short = "TQQQ" THEN LastPrice * Volume ELSE 0 END) - 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Stock_Short = "SQQQ" THEN LastPrice * Volume ELSE 0 END) 
  ) AS difference 
FROM aktien 
WHERE Stock_Short IN ("TQQQ","SQQQ")
GROUP BY TradeDate 
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC
```

Comment: why so complicated? Why does not work my solution?  `SELECT a.Stock_Short,a.TradeDate,b.Stock_Short,a.lastprice - b.lastprice from aktien a join aktien b on a.TradeDate = b.TradeDate where a.Stock_Short = 'TQQQ' and b.Stock_Short = 'SQQQ' ;

Comment: @NoobPython I have optimized the code considerably. I realized that there is no need to use Sub-select query; Please check the updated answer, and let me know if it still works or not.

Comment: @NoobPython and what's the result ?

Comment: see below. thanks. i think the join is slightly more intensive calculation wise. but safer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Madhur's above solution as well as the solution by Walter.

I have modified it slightly

```
SELECT a.TradeDate,(a.lastprice*a.Volume) - (b.lastprice*b.Volume) as USDflow 
from aktien a join aktien b on a.TradeDate = b.TradeDate where a.Stock_Short =    
'TQQQ' and b.Stock_Short = 'SQQQ' order by TradeDate desc ;
```

This gives the same result as Madhurs takes 0.029s for the query. therefore slightly longer.

But i think the advantage of this solution is the treatment of the TradeDate.
If a TradeDate is missing for one the JOIN will ignore this TradeDate whereas Madhurs solution will calculate the sum/difference still.

Thanks to both!